# How to spin two components at a same time in uipickerview

Tags: ios, uipickerview

It is my first app that I am trying to build in Iphone and I have some problems.I am using uipicker view in my app in which i am storing data coming from server. problem is that i have two components i want to spin both components at a same time not one by one.How it can done.
below is code

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 2;


}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return self.jsonresultarr.count;


}
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    return [[self.jsonresultarr objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"Company_Id"];

    return [[self.jsonresultarr objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"Company_name"];





}
```

I want to move these two components at a same time ??

Comment: i had mentioned i want to move spin two components at a same time.. when i am movin first component second is still in its position... i want to move both components at a same time.

Comment: Can't you just put the contents of both in a single section?

Comment: like how i had done also like this but still same issue?

Comment: see my updated question like that u r saying ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be more easily done by having a single section and displaying all of your information in that section formatted.

To do that, return 1 in numberOfComponentsInPickerView (or omit that method as I believe the default is 1). In titleForRow, create a string that has the information from both of the keys.

```
NSObject *companyId = [[self.jsonresultarr objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"Company_Id"];
NSObject *companyName = [[self.jsonresultarr objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"Company_name"];
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", companyId, companyName, nil];
```

Comment: if i want to give title above them like copmany id and company name what can i do then ?

Comment: Usually that is handled outside of the control. Perhaps a label above. Hard to say without seeing what you are trying to display and how it's laid out.